# I am new on rails i not sure what is going on my code but I want to filter data from database by searching using id how can i do it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying generate a code that tracks for documents that revolve within the organisation. I have done other codes for adding employees, adding document types and logging in now I am struggling on creating a document form and search from the document that I have created. This code is for searching:

```
controller#show  
    def show
        @generate_documents = GenerateDocument.where('Reciever LIKE?',"%#{params[:search]}%")
        # @generate_documents = GenerateDocument.all
      end

views/show
    <%= form_tag generate_document_path, :method => :get do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
    <!-- end of seaerch form -->


    <!-- loading data from database and displaying then in a list format BEGIN -->
    <ul> 
      <% @generate_documents.each do |generate_document| %>
      <li>


         <%= link_to generate_document.Reciever, edit_generate_document_path(generate_document) %>
          </li>
      <% end %>`enter code here`
    </ul>
    <!-- 
    END LISTING -->

    <%= link_to 'New Generate Document', new_generate_document_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even Iam new to rails, but i can help you with basics that you need to pass the parameters from the view to the controller, therefore you can use:

```
    :url => {:controller => "name_of_your_controller", :action => "action_to_be_perforemed", :id => "whatever id you want"}
```

or else you can also pass the object within the url like we do while edit request

```
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@edit)%>
```

which will give the :id of the particular post. 
Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh  that helped me a lot , i have also noticed that i had misspelled "receiver" after i have fixed it  worked.